Smaller lexicographically sequence of advertisement that can be formed from given pairs of advertisements
Recently I gave Flipkart Online assessment and I was stuck at a question for a very long time. The question goes like this. An advertisement company has array of pairs of advertisements and each advertisement should be played one after another. It will be beneficial for the company to start from "ABC" advertisement if given. We have to find the sequence in which all the advertisements should be played for at least once. If multiple such ways are possible give Lexicographically smaller one.
For example:
4 
"XYZ", "IOP" 
"QWE", "XYZ" 
"ABC", "TUV" 
"TUV", "QWE"

The sequence possible is starting from "ABC"->"TUV"->"QWE"->"XYZ"->"IOP"
I couldn't come up with an approach in the stipulated time. After I thought for a bit is this similar in finding whether starting from a source a connected graph could be possible or not and then see for the smallest order.
Can someone help me if other approaches are also possible or is this a correct way of deducing this?

Looks like path finding in a graph.

can you elaborate your approach?

I don't think so because there can be a test case like this ABC, XYZ XYZ,PQR PQR,TUV TUV,XYZ XYZ,MNO.    The answe could be something like this ABC->XYZ->PQR->TUV->XYZ->MNO

There are no such constraints that were given in the question. It was mentioned that we had to find a path where all the advertisements are visited at least once.

Why not sorting with a comparison function that first compare using the constraints and second using lexicographic order? ABC<XYZ XYZ<PQR PQR<TUV TUV<XYZ XYZ<MNO : would give ABC-XYZ-MNO-PQR-TUV

You can sort all the outgoing edges from each node, then perform a modified topological sort starting from node ABC. (This is assuming that a valid solution exists.)
Example implementation in C++:
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
std::unordered_map<std::string, 
    std::priority_queue<std::string, std::vector<std::string>, std::greater<>>> adj;
void toposort(std::string s, std::vector<std::string>& res) {
    while (!adj[s].empty()) {
        auto next = adj[s].top();
        adj[s].pop();
        toposort(next, res);
    }
    res.push_back(s);
}
std::vector<std::string> solve(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> edges) {
    adj.clear();
    for (auto& [from, to] : edges) adj[from].push(to);
    std::vector<std::string> res;
    toposort("ABC", res);
    return std::vector(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
}


Checking for the existence of a solution is left as an exercise.
